# 14.04 Touchpad is too sensitive

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad is way too sensitive. While writing, the cursor jumps suddenly to the place the mouse cursor is sitting. I am not even touching the touchpad! I had the same problem with 12.04 and recently did an upgrade to 14.04, which didn't solve the problem.

In the mouse-and-touchpad settings, there are only settings for a mouse, not a touchpad. I have tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install gsynaptics

gpointing-device-settings
```

which didn't help.

Then I found [this](http://redoem.com/2011/07/04/enable-full-touchpad-functionality-in-ubuntu/) which might describe my problem.

But I get stuck halfway through. When putting this in the terminal:

(Add the patch to the psmouse module:)

`sudo dkms add -m psmouse -v elantech-v6`

I get this:

> Error! Could not find module source directory.
>   Directory: /usr/src/psmouse-elantech-v6 does not exist.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 56):

```
xinput list
```

will give your device name (look for TouchPad)

```
xinput list-props "Touchpad Name"
```

This will give the available properties of your touchpad. You will probably find that the property is still "Synaptics ..." based, which means that you would type something like:

```
xinput set-prop "Touchpad Name" "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255
```

I use the following properties (replace ***Touchpad Name*** with yours from the `xinput list` command) for mine to reduce the overall sensitivity:

```
xinput set-prop "Touchpad Name" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20
xinput set-prop "Touchpad Name" "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255
```

The above 2 commands seem to do the trick for me. Before them my touchpad was basically unusable.

Comment: I had to set "Synaptics Finger" to 100 110 255 before it made much difference on my machine. Also, I recommend keeping "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" low like 10 10 as it doesn't help solve the oversensitivity problem and makes the touchpad seem laggy when set higher.

Comment: I had to tweak mind, but used different params for my lenovo yoga 2. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Matthew Fisher :

Comment: I checked the name of my touchpad and it is SynPS/2 Synaptics . Then I tried the "list-props" comand and found: herman@homepc:~/Documents$ xinput list-props Synaptics
unable to find device Synaptics Any help here? Thanks.

Comment: On MSI GT72 6QD best is xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 50 50 255

Comment: Does this need to be run at every startup?

Comment: @HermanJaramillo It's already late. Though for anybody looking at this later, you are supposed to enter the full name of the touchpad, e.g. "SynPS/2 Synaptics", not just the last part.

Comment: reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Adjust_Touchpad_Sensitivity

Comment: Instead of entering the name you can also enter the `id` as returned by `xinput`. Much less hard to type.

Comment: @AndrewMao yes. unless you follow the instructions in this answer to persist across restarts https://askubuntu.com/a/20308/285208

Answer (score 12):

How about [this manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html) which has a list of commands you can supposedly use. The arguments "50 90 225" as given in the other answers are explained in these docs to represent values for "low, high, and press." I don't know what *my* original values were, but ..."Synaptics Finger" 5 16 225 has made my system tolerable.

Comment: Those settings are a great improvement on my Lenovo T450S

Comment: Don't know why but this seems to have made accidental dragging much easier. Any idea on how to relieve that?

Comment: @xji same problem here. Would love to know how to stop accidental palm touches repositioning my cursor.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem with Toshiba C-50
This solved my problem:

```
xinput list
xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" | grep -i finger
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255
```

Here, SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad is the name of your touchpad which get listed when you type in xinput list in terminal.Replace SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad by Your Device Name.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/269354/107496)

Comment: Sorry, I need some more help. When I type in the list-props command, I get this: Device 'FSPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad'. What do I do afterwards?

Comment: I mean, what do I type in instead of "synaptics finger"? I typed in `xinput set-prop "FSPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad" "Sentelic Finger" 50 90 255` and got this: `property 'Sentelic Finger' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`.

Comment: You shoudld Type
    xinput list-props "SPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad'" | grep -i finger
Then Type
    xinput set-prop "'FSPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad" " Sentelic  Finger" 50 90 255

Comment: that's exactly what I did. And what I got out was what I copied in above: "property 'Sentelic Finger' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format"

Comment: Could you tell what the numbers mean 50 90 255? I have by default like this `Synaptics Finger (267): 25, 30, 0`
Under Win7 touchpad is less sensitive and just the way it should be.

Comment: ideally the other `xinput` answer ( https://askubuntu.com/a/539181/17060  ) should have been a comment to this (or vice versa, whichever was first), but for reference, here's the reference page that might be more current:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Answer (score 5):

There is a command line tool called `synclient`. If you write `man synclient` in console it says:

> This program  lets  you  change  your  Synaptics  TouchPad  driver 
>   for XOrg/XFree86 server parameters while X is running.

There is also a GUI for the tool, called `gpointing-device-settings`, but it doesn't offer nearly as many options as the command line tool. The only caveat to using the command line tool is that there are so many options.

You can read [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tweak-your-touchpad-to-taste-in-linux/) by Jack Wallen for more details.

Answer (score 5):

The general solution to this problem is not to dial down the touchpad sensitivity, but to enable palm detection so that resting your palm while typing doesn't trigger a click. For example, I have `libinput` installed and put the following in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"                                                                                                                        
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"                                                                                             
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"                                                                                                                
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"                                                                                                 
        Driver "libinput"                                                                                                                   
        Option "Tapping" "True"                                                                                                             
        Option "PalmDetection" "True"                                                                                                       
        Option "TappingDragLock" "True"                                                                                                     
EndSection
```

For more information, check out these other relevant posts:

- [Proper touchpad thumb & palm detection with libinput](https://askubuntu.com/q/649103/86161)
- [How do I disable the touchpad while typing?](https://askubuntu.com/q/886092/86161)
- [Touchpad issue: jumping cursor while typing (Ubuntu 14.04), syndaemon don't help](https://askubuntu.com/q/462135/86161)

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver, the directory is `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, not `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on many variants of linux. Currently I am on Elementary OS Loki. I had automated the fix of this problem by creating following shell script at /etc/X11/Xsession.d/56touchpadfix:

```
export `xinput list | grep -i touchpad | awk '{ print $6 }'`
xinput --set-prop "$id" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20
xinput --set-prop "$id" "Synaptics Finger" 35 45 250
xinput --set-prop "$id" "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" 180 180
true
```

You need to tune values for your hardware. Mine work for Sony SVS series laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Dell, there is a solution for this. This may also be applicable even if you do not have a Dell laptop, as long as you update certain steps. I have a Dell Inpsiron 13 7000 series, and the following solution worked perfectly for me.

These instructions come directly from Dell in this article [Precision / XPS: Ubuntu General Touchpad/Mouse Issue Fix](http://www.dell.com/support/article/hk/en/hkbsd1/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en). The issue seems to be that Synaptics drivers override Dell's. You need to disable Synaptics.

The first portion did wonders for me. Here is the script that they suggest adding to `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf`. I do not recommend following the accepted answer's solutions as that route seems to create other problems.

```
# Disable generic Synaptics device, as we're using
# "DLL0704:01 06CB:76AE Touchpad"
# Having multiple touchpad devices running confuses syndaemon
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

For compatability comparison, I've a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 series with `xinput list`

```
jonathan@Dell:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0741:00 06CB:7E7E Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

Synaptics is not on that list because it has been disabled by the above script. Before adding this script, I suggest running `xinput --test <id>"` (for me `14`). If you get output on a terminal, that means your device is working (your device is "on").

After rebooting, you will then need to install `libinput` with the following command `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput libinput-tools`.

After `libinput` installation, you'll need to update `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf` per your preferrences. Here is mine for example

```
# Match on all types of devices but tablet devices and joysticks
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "TapingDrag" "True"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
    Option "AccelProfile" "adaptive"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "0.2"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

And that's it, no more sensitive touchpad!