# Can I make 3 finger drag switch to desktop?

Tags: touchpad

I dual boot Win 10 - Ubuntu. ON WIndows 10 if I swipe downwards with 3 fingers, it minimizes all the windows and goes to the desktop, if you swipe upwards with 3 fingers, it'll re-focus all the windows back.

Is there a way I can make it do the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: For libinput you might be interested in [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures). My touchpad unfortunately doesn't recognize gestures *(i.e. 5 point of trobleshooting)*, so it doesn't work for me, but it should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

There is an application that allows you to use specific gestures to issue commands, this may let you enable support for 3 finger gestures. The program is called easystroke. Its in the software center. You can search by the following name: Easystroke Gesture Recognition.

Here is a [link](http://easystroke.sourceforge.net/) to the developers website.

You can also check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/684745/710635) already answered question. Which states:

> In Ubuntu `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is used. It can detect only
>   2-finger swipes, vertical and horizontal.
>
> There is no code that detects 3-finger swipes. The only way to add
>   this feature is to code it into the user space driver.

So I guess checking out the application is the better choice.

Comment: Could you include the specific steps to achieve the result?

Comment: I am sorry but I am on Desktop. There is an option to record action after you launch the application. Probably you will be able to record the gesture there. I haven't tried this application myself yet, but this is the only one I could find.