# Ubuntu synaptics touchpad mouse move over buttons doesn't work

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I've just installed Kubuntu 15.04 on my Asus X502C and have a problem with touchpad.
When I start dragging mouse outside the buttons area all works fine, I can drag mouse over all touchpad and it works.
But then I want to start dragging over the button area, cursor doesn't move. I've tried several settings, but have no solution yet.

My config now is:

```
LeftEdge                = 1308
RightEdge               = 4804
TopEdge                 = 1238
BottomEdge              = 5000
FingerLow               = 15
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 215
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 96
HorizScrollDelta        = 100
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0406009
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 2
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.10472
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 5000
HorizHysteresis         = 8
VertHysteresis          = 8
ClickPad                = 0
```

I don't need area above the buttons, because I use taps for clicking so I want to use it for mouse dragging.
How to change behaviour of the touchpad?

```
    nikolay@Nikolay-PC:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Added all to the question

Answer (score 0):

There was this kind of problem with some touchpads in `xorg-synaptics` driver.

You can try to use `libinput` instead.

[Here is the manual to install it](https://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850).

Comment: It was 0 at first, but all changes I've made doesn't affect on this bottom button area.
If i set it to 2000, for example, I'll have small strip near the top edge of working touchpad. And then If I'll set it to 3600 of more I'll have what I have now. For now I've changed BottomEdge to 3634 and AreaBottomEdge to 0, as It was initially.

Comment: You can try to install `libinput`.

Comment: I've installed libinput. Still has the same problem :(
When I start dragging from outside of the buttons and then move to them all works fine. Can't understand why I can't start dragging over the buttons.