# Where can I find a driver for an Epson XP-424? What is the process to install the driver once I find one?

Tags: epson

I'm looking for a driver for an Epson XP-424 printer.  Where can  I find one and what is the process to install once I find one?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the drivers at [Epson Drivers Site](https://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850)

Search for your modelm download and install deb file according to your Ubuntu architecture.

If you have a 64-bit Ubuntu, you will need `amd64` deb files.

For scanner driver you will need `iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7` package, not `ltdl3` one.