# Two finger scrolling and two finger pointer moving if 1 finger is in lower 20%

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, click-policy

My problem is that my touchpad is actually a click pad (HP Envy 14 Beats) and lower 20% of it are split into right and left buttons.

On Windows before I used to have it like that: If I start my 2 finger action in the upper 80%, it is recognised as 2 finger scroll, but if I hold 1 finger on (for example) left button (finger is in the lower 20% to the left), then I can simply move the pointer around with my second finger in the upper 80%.

At the moment if i am touching the left button (touching clickpad in the bottom) and try to move the pointer, my action is recognised as 2 finger scroll.

Is there any way I could adjust the touchpad so that it would be same as on Windows before?

I searched a lot of internet for it and didn't find anything relevant, hence, please share a link if a solution to this problem already exists.

Thank you!

Comment: This is an issue with Ubuntu's touchpad drivers. As of now, there is no known fix. I have the same issue on my Dell Inspiron 5558. You may try `synclient Clickpad=1`, worked for some other people.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in a new version of `xorg-synaptics`. At least it has been fixed for me. Try Ubuntu 15.10 or install a HWE to 14.04.

Also `libinput` can be used instead of `xorg-synaptics`. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/649103/167850).

Comment: and what do i do next once I have HWE on my 14.04 machine?

Comment: I still have exactly the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04. If anyone knows how to fix it, please let me know! Thanks