# How do I move mouse's arrow with 1 index finger on topside of touchpad while other index finger touches left bottom area of the touchpad?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

How do I move the pointer around with one index finger on the topside of the touchpad while my other index finger is static and touching the left bottom side of the touchpad?
I can do this in Windows 10 but for some reason the mouse arrow does not move in Ubuntu when I do this.

system:Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 5.4.0-050400-generic and LXDE as desktop environment.

Thanks

Comment: If anyone shared a fix, I would appreciate it. I just found someone's post describing exactly the same problem I described: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706369/two-finger-scrolling-and-two-finger-pointer-moving-if-1-finger-is-in-lower-20

Comment: I tried this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1026046 It worked but it broke something as well. Now the mouse acceleration is slow even if I set Accel Speed to its maximum, 0.999, with the following command: `xinput set-prop 23 "libinput Accel Speed"` Does anyone know how to fix this slow mouse acceleration?

Comment: The following worked to fix the slow speed problem: `sudo xinput set-prop 23 "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000`

Comment: For making this last change persistent, the touchpad section of the file 90-libinput.conf must be updated as follows: ```Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
            Option "Tapping" "True"
            Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
            Option "TransformationMatrix" "4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"
EndSection```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf to file 90-libinput.conf in the same folder and updating 90-libinput.conf as follows fixes the problem:

```
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
     MatchIsTouchpad "on"
     MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
     Driver "libinput"
         Option "Tapping" "True"
         Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
         Option "TransformationMatrix" "4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"
EndSection
```

Comment: I attempted to clean up the "update", please verify that it shows what you actually added to the file.