# Clickpad not working properly

Tags: touchpad, 15.10, toshiba

I have a Toshiba M50-A11-L with a Clickpad.

When I put my finger on the Clickpad and click with the mouse and then drag it, it doesn't recognize my second finger.

I can't click and drag.

Update:
The clicking works. But the acceleration is too linear. On Synaptics when i move slow the cursor dont go far. When i move fast the cursor is moving trough the whole screen. But with libinut the cursor alway travels the same distance no matter how fast i move with the touchpad.

Comment: How is this question related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry. I use Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

You can install [libinput](https://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850) instead of xorg-synaptics. It handles this type of cases better.

Another option is to use a newer version of xorg-synaptics. In some cases this kind of issues have been fixed.

But you did not mention the current version.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: I intsalled libinput but i dont like the acceleration. It is so bad!!! Synaptics has muh better acceleration.

Comment: But what about the clicking? Acceleration can be tuned.

Comment: The clicking works. But the acceleration is too linear. On Synaptics when i move slow the cursor dont go far. When i move fast the cursor is moving trough the whole screen. But with libinut the cursor alway travels the same distance no matter how fast i move with the touchpad.

Comment: Can someone help me please!