# T460s Trackpad / Trackpoint caveats

Tags: 15.10, touchpad, lenovo, trackpoint

I have a fresh installation on a new T460s laptop running version 15.10. A couple things I've noticed that are really irritating, hopefully someone has some resolutions.

1. Trackpoint scroll not working
2. Trackpoint click and drag not working
3. When typing, trackpad registers palm and moves/clicks cursor.
4. Multitouch not perfect - If you rest your thumb on the click section of the pad, it will register as two finger scroll. This will also prevent click and drags sometimes.
5. Cursor jumps to random spot on screen - I think this has something to do with the trackpad, but only happens sometimes.

Im wondering if switching to v14 will be different.

xinput:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer    (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜     ↳ Logitech M705                               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest installing `libinput` instead of using `xorg-synaptics`.

`lininput` is available in Ubuntu 15.10 repositories. Install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

By default tapping is disabled in libinput. To enable it. you need to edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-libinput.conf` and add

```
Option "Tapping" "True"
```

to "InputClass" section, before EndSection.

In newer versions of `libinput`, e.g. available for Ubuntu 16.04, the file is called `90-libinput.conf` and the file have a few sections.

In this case you need to add `Option "Tapping" "True"` to the touchpad section.

Comment: I added that package and it seems to help with all those issues except the scroll with the trackpoint. I'm also trying to find that file to edit, but I dont have an "X11" folder

Comment: This can't be. Please post output of `ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Comment: I lied, sorry, its there after reboot.

Tap to click on the trackpad id working now. Thank you! But any ideas on  the trackpoint?

Comment: is this package available in 14.04?

Comment: No, but you can install it from source. http://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850

Answer (score 1):

The trackpoint issue is a kernel bug, see here [1] and [2]. I don't know when the fix will be made available, but it will also be pushed to 15.10. I am running 16.04 beta with this patch and it works fine (with the synaptics driver, no change to xorg.conf)

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1553811

[2] bugzilla bug id 114321

If you you are brave, you can try the kernel image I just built that incorporates this and another T460s relevant bugfixes (freeze on lid close) [3].

[3] https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7190A65F7B8264CA!374&authkey=!ANfEebLzhVWcYLo&ithint=folder%2cdeb

Comment: Thank you, I did find that out also. I'm not familiar with applying a patch. Do you know how its possible for me to see when this patch will be pushed?