# Thinkpad 440p Trackpad: several problems

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I recently installed Kubuntu for the first time on my Thinkpad 440 and there are three issues I'm having with the trackpad:

1) Size of the middle click zone

On Windows, there was a fairly large region I could press and have it be registered as a middle click. On Kubuntu, that region is smaller, and it's screwing up my muscle memory -- I end up left- or right-clicking when I mean to middle click. Is there a way to enlarge the zone that counts as a middle click?

[pink zone is what it is on Kubuntu, yellow zone is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPa6l.png)

2) Top strip

If I **begin** swiping my finger across this top strip, the cursor doesn't move. It only moves once I bring my finger down to the lower region. If I start in the lower region and move up, it continues to work. Is there a way to disable this annoying behavior and have the entire trackpad work for cursor movement first time?

[orange zone is where cursor doesn't move if my finger begins there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZPuK.png)

3) Dragging

On Windows, if I was dragging an object and moved my finger to the edge of the trackpad, the cursor would continue moving in a straight line until I released my finger. On Kubuntu this isn't the case and I can't find an option to enable it. How do I get this functionality?

(I should also note that these same issues appeared when I tried Ubuntu, so it's not unique to Kubuntu.)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Did you try libinput?

Comment: 16.04, no I haven't. I'm a novice so I don't know what that would involve.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, reboot and try. This is another (a new generation) user space driver.

Comment: No, this has made the problem worse. In addition to the above, now tap-clicking does not work at all and the sensitivity and acceleration are sky-high. I went into the settings menu and everything is now greyed out.

Comment: Tap cliciking is disabled by default in libinput. See http://askubuntu.com/a/678122/167850  You can always remove that package. Acceleration can be tuned too. GUI settings do not work. But I suggest checking other issues.

Comment: Is there a list of options that can be changed anywhere? The stuff on the libinput site don't look anything like config file you linked

Comment: You can change settings in that config file or using `xinput`.

Comment: What are the names of the options to change though? They don't match up with what xinput lists at any rate, because I tried adding "AccelSpeed" "0" in various combinations (with and without spaces, with and without quotes, "False", etc) and it didn't turn off acceleration.

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man4/libinput.4.html For xinput read `man xinput`. You can set options there too.

Answer (score 0):

ArchLinux user here. I own a Thinkpad x260, with physical buttons, but i wanted to remove the 'two invisible buttons' at the bottom of my trackpad.

My solution went trought this program:

```
synclient
```

Use this to see all configurable options:

```
synclient -l
```

More information for Ubuntu users here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad