# How to configure Touchpad in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: touchpad

Ubuntu 16.04 - there is no option for configuration of Touchpad like: "disable during typing", "palm detection".

Is there any workaround (as typing has become difficult issue)?

Comment: is there a **mouse & touchpad** on all settings ?? http://i.imgur.com/NxATSbJ.png

Comment: Go to All Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> Device Tab -> Choose (Elantech) Touchpad from the scroll-down list -> Go to Touchpad Tab -> Check `Disable touchpad while typing' option.

Comment: @ipselute I also don't see a "devices tab" on the "Mouse and Touchpad" section of Settings.  The only options under the touchpad section at "Mouse and Touchpad" are: pointer speed, tap to click, 2 finger scrolling, and natural scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried xinput ?

```
xinput
```

This will show  all your device, note the ID for your touchpad.

```
xinput --watch-props <device number>
```

Above command will show the properties for your device, if you can see a propertly lik "libinput Disable While Typing Enabled" you  are good to go.

```
xinput set-prop 13 "libinput Disable While Typing Enabled" 1
```

The above command will fix it for you.

Regards,
Shivam

Comment: Thanks Shivam, I did find out number of my device and list of property also but there was no line like" libinput Disable While Typing Enabled". I could locate palm detection property set to 0 but could not made any change in it

Comment: Hi Kamlesh! Are you able to check  the version of xinput using  `xinput -v`. Mine is ( xinput version 1.6.2 XI version on server: 2.3). What all properties can you see?

Comment: Just another follow up, have you got libinput installed? This can be used in ubuntu 15.10+. Please refer [link](these:http://askubuntu.com/questions/649103/proper-touchpad-thumb-palm-detection-with-libinput/678122#678122)

Comment: The thing is a bit of a bummer nowadays with libinput there. We probably need to wait till the whole functionality gets ported to the new architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Installing touch pad indicator form this link http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/atareao_atareao/xenial/main/base/touchpad-indicator had given me some configuration help. I am able to disable touch pad while typing, but it crash frequently.

Comment: it is working well with Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: After some work around  I cam across https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316240, I came to know actually I was running two touch pad , with this work around every thing seems to be working fine

Comment: Always crash upon launch, its also removed from atareao's repository