# How to permanently disable the “tap dragging”-feature in Ubuntu 18.04 (libinput) without disabling “tap to click”?

Tags: 18.04, xorg, touchpad, thinkpad, libinput

I have got almost the same question as [How to disable the "tap dragging"-feature in Ubuntu 18.04 (libinput) without disabling "tap to click"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032459/how-to-disable-the-tap-dragging-feature-in-ubuntu-18-04-libinput-without-dis?rq=1), but I don't have enough reputation to comment it.

Like there I want to disable the possibility to drag and drop or mark texts with the touch pad without clicking in Ubuntu 18.04.

Like proposed there in the almost-same-question and in the post (https://askubuntu.com/a/935662/865596) I tried to set an option in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "TappingDrag" "false"
EndSection
```

Reboot but tap dragging is still there :(

Until here my question is a duplicate, but now I start with my question to the same problem:

On the man page of libinput https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput it is written:

> It is recommended that libinput devices are configured through the InputClass directive (refer to xorg.conf(5)) instead of manual per-device configuration.

What does that mean? And how can I do so? I don't even find that xorg.conf file on my Ubuntu 18.04 (I am completely new with Ubuntu)

I have heard that xorg.conf has a higher priority than .../xorg.conf.d/... files. Maybe this is the source of the problem?

Another potential problem source: There is a file called 70-wacom.conf in my .../xorg.conf.d/ folder. As 70 is higher than 40 this could also be a problem, because there is also an Touchpad section in this file, but there are no pecific options stated in this file. Could this still be the source of the problem? In the according man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/wacom.4.html I found:

> Left  click  drag:  tap  to select, quickly (within TapTime period) touch selection again.
>          Then drag.  Available on touchpads, e.g. BambooPT, not touchscreens.

I think this also describes the phenomena I want to disable. But I don't know the syntax for the wacom.config file. And I don't understand which driver is responsible for the touch pad of my Thinkpad x380,

The answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1035508/865596 to the almost-same question works for me temporarily: When I use

```
xinput set-prop 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad' 'libinput Tapping Drag Enabled' 0
```

the tap dragging is deactivated until I restart my Thinkpad.

In this solution he suggested:

> The way I set this permanently is by putting into a script that runs
>   on login.

but I doubt that this is a very elegant solution and I have no idea how to do so.

I don't know what "Xorg" and "Wayland" means.

I would be very happy to understand what is going on here (eg why editing the config file doesn't help and how all these drivers interact with each other) and/or an easy to use solution for my problem to deactivate tap dragging.

Edit: As requested in the comments by [pm-b](https://askubuntu.com/users/709099/pm-b), I added the following outputs:

```
jakob@jakobThinkPadX380Yoga:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]


jakob@jakobThinkPadX380Yoga:~$ xinput list-props 14
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (307): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (308): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (309):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (310):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (311):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (312):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (313):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (314):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (315):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (316):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (317):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (318):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (319):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (320):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (321):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (322): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (323):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (324):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (325):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (326):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (327): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (328): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (329): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (330): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (264): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (265):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (266):    0, 0
    Device Node (267):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (268):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (331):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (332):   1

jakob@jakobThinkPadX380Yoga:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `xinput list` and then run `xinput list-props` with the device id of your touchpad?

Comment: Also, please run `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and update your question with the output. This is to find out if you are currently using Xorg or Wayland.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've added the outputs like you suggested