# Enable middle click drag on synaptics clickpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a Macbook Air 6,2 which is equipped with a synaptics clickpad. I have managed to turn on middle click emulation when three fingers are pressed on the trackpad. This works but I noticed that when the middle click is recognized the mouse cursor is locked in place. However, I need to use a middle click drag operation to manipulate the views in Blender and Freecad, which I can not do because the mouse cursor is locked in place.

Is there anyway to configure the click pad so that it does not lock the cursor when a three finger emulated middle click is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to switch to `libinput` then configure it via `.conf` file.

A pretty complete guide is here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput

If you can't switch it off, try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: Switching to libinput worked. Although I followed [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649103/proper-touchpad-thumb-palm-detection-with-libinput/678122#678122) guide to enable libinput since I am using Ubuntu instead of Arch.

Comment: What config options did you guys actually use? I'm on libinput, with tap-to-drag enabled, but middle clicking drag is not working out of the box.