# libinput: How to map different Tappings to Buttons, TappingButtonMap has no effect

Tags: touchpad, xinput, tap-to-click

My touchdpad has two buttons (not tapping) and I used to configure two-finger tapping as middle click with synclient.

Now, with ubuntu-gnome 16.10, libinput is the way to go and I tried to achieve the same without success until now.

I tried the approaches mentioned in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput. I have a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf with

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "libinput"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
    Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
EndSection
```

which does not have effect. I can use

```
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
```

Then two-finger-tap works for middle click, but the real right button will be a middle-click, too. I also tried a set of scripts and gnome configurations without success until now. Is there any solution with libinput, or do I have to switch back to synclient?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already discovered, the option you want is TappingButtonMap.

```
Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
```

The issue is seemingly that Ubuntu 16.10 ships with version 0.19.0 of xserver-xorg-input-libinput. The property you (and I) want was added in a later version. Version 0.23.0-1 that ships in the development version of 17.04 supports it according to the documentation.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man4/libinput.4.html

Comment: No problem. I was looking for the same thing and your question saved me from messing needlessly with the button mappings.

I need to use libinput to have working palm rejection/detection on my Dell Precision M5510 work laptop so I can't really use the Synaptics driver where remapping the buttons worked just fine. If you have a touchpad that supposedly works well with that driver you could give that a try.

Comment: @blunden A good answer +1

Comment: It is possible to install `libinput` from source. See http://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I am considering doing so myself to be able to use the supposedly better acceleration code in libinput 1.6 and later versions (as well as to be able to remap the taps). In that case, I intend to follow your instructions but probably use 'checkinstall,' both to get deb packages and for easier removal than what you get with "make install".

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried it now and the two projects built and installed without errors. However, when booting up I lost all input (keyboard and touchpad) because the broken libinput took over. I had to boot an Ubuntu live image, mount my encrypted drive and remove /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf and my custom config in /etc to get it back. I then tried a clean build without checkinstall where I followed your instructions completely (besides using "1.6-branch" instead of master for libinput). Obviously I don't blame you but I was wondering if you have tried building libinput recently?

Comment: @blunden No I did not build it recently. I am quite happy with the version form the repos.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the xorg.conf option in blunden's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/886614) above,

```
Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
```

you can also manually set it as

```
xinput set-prop $ID "libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled" 0, 1
```

for "lmr" or 1, 0, where $ID is the device id. Found the man pages of libinput, [link](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-libinput/).

Comment: I'd upvote your answer 10 times if I could, for the `xinput` command sample.

Answer (score 0):

`libinput` in `xenial` and `yakkety` does not have the `TappingButtonMap` option.

You can use `ButtonMapping`, but as you noticed the physical buttons will be remapped too.

You can always revert to `synaptics` by

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

You can also install a newer version of `libinput` that does support `ButtonMapping`. See [THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850) for how-to.

Comment: Thus, the documentation for https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Button_re-mapping is a bit confusing, right? 
I don't find the hint that these options only work with synaptics. In the opposite, they mention libinput as drop-in replacement for synaptics.

Comment: This option will work with a new version of `libinput`.