# How do I fix: Horizontal scrolling freez4es my UI?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have a Figureworks iGesture Pad (discontinued. was the company Apple bought for their patents to use in their touchpads).

For whatever reason, on Ubuntu, a horizontal scroll event freezes Ubuntu for a few seconds and does not horizontally scroll. Every other gesture works fine.

I'd be very happy to get horizontal scrolling working. And a bit happy to simply disable it so Ubuntu won't freeze.

Note that no tool (Settings, Compiz Settings, (Unity) Tweak Tool) provide any relevant setting.

I tried some xinput settings e.g. `xinput set-prop 9 "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 6 7 4 5` with no luck.

I'm on 16.04 if it matters.

Comment: If you open up `journalctl -f` — do there any messages appear for making the horizontal scroll?

Comment: @Hi-Angel no, nothing shows up.

Comment: Okay, so, I don't know if 16.04 is using libinput by default yet or not, but judging [by this questiotn/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906562/problem-installing-libinput-on-16-04-2) it doesn't. So, as steps to fix the problem I recommend: α) installing libinput, then rebooting; if it didn't help β) either build latest libinput or install from a PPA; then if you still have some problem, γ) [report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting_bugs.html#reporting_bugs_touchpad) — the maintainer is very active, so you'll likely get a reply within a day or so.