# Error message when login in after installing libinput and modifying the 90-libinput.conf file

Tags: 16.04, xorg, touchpad, libinput

So I wanted my touchpad to be disabled when I am typing. I am on Ubuntu 16.04. I found about libinput and followed the instructions in this example [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649103/proper-touchpad-thumb-palm-detection-with-libinput/678122#678122). the second answer by @JimB was followed. **before installing libinput I did the following command "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core"** because without doing this the libinput instalation command was giving some dependency error like

> "The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:xserver-xorg-input-libinput : Depends: xserver-xorg-core
>   (>= 2:1.17.99.902)E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages".

after following through all the steps when I log out and log back in I get the following error message box.[image: Error Message] Once I click ok the box is gone and my screen is initially black but later turns back to normal, my system seems to working ok, just the mouse pointer now moves a little too fast & login is slow now upon bootup. Now what can I do to resolve this issue and bring my system back to how it was.

Comment: You probably have 16.04.2. Then the correct package is `xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04`.

Comment: @Pilot6 you are right my Ubuntu version is 16.04.2 LTS. So now what should I do exactly, to undo what I have done or otherwise fix the problem?

Comment: I got tired explaining that the 16.04.2 does not mean anything. The important part is which version you initially installed and which hwe stack is there. It is too complex to fix it in some cases. A long thread is needed to find out the current state of your system. For the future: do not run commands that you do not understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @karel this question is more than 2 years old, at that time I might have just reinstalled Ubuntu entirely, and since then I have move onto a new laptop that's Windows only, so I have no way of knowing if the link you have given would have helped, but thanks for taking the time to post that link. Maybe someday in the future someone in a similar situation will stumble upon this link and it might help them.