# Upgrade libinput to 1.7 or 1.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, xps, libinput

Is there any way to have libinput 1.8 or 1.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 without breaking everything? There are issues with touchpad tap sensitivty on the Dell XPS 13 and Xenial's version of libinput (1.6.3) does not allow adjusting sensitivity.

If it is possible, how would I go about upgrading this package? Adding a PPA? Compiling? If the former, which PPA and if the latter, how should I compile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options.

1. You can try to install `libinput10` version 1.8 from `artful` repository.
   You can get it [HERE](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/libinput10/download)
   There may be problems with dependencies.
2. You can compile and install `libinput` from source using 
   [THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/a/651008/167850)