# Synaptics touchpad not responding after kernel update

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I did a software update from my 3.13 Ubuntu kernel, and it took away my Intel 3460 wifi drivers so I didnt have internet anymore.. I then had to install the newer 4.04 kernel, and after the reboot the wifi came back but now my SynPS/2 laptop touchpad isnt working.. On `xinput`I see my pointer as SynPS/2 with id 12 as a slave pointer (2), however I also see a DLL06F0 UNKNOWN slave pointer which on doing `xinput -list-props 15` shows a change on every key press so it looks like the keyboard ? Ive been trying to fix this forever now and either wifi fix on 3.13 or mouse fix on 4.04 would be truly appreciated!

Comment: What version of ubuntu? And i may be mixing them up, but I think synaptics is deprecated and everyone has all but moved to libinput

Comment: I'm on version 14.04 as of now. Do you think moving from synaptics to libinput should solve it? Any comment on how to do this ?

Comment: It might? you might check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/649103/proper-touchpad-thumb-palm-detection-with-libinput

Comment: Do you think doing this from 3.13 kernel will also add this for 4.04 kernel? Asking because Ill have to boot to 3.13 and use Ethernet to get both mouse and internet for this..

Comment: I think it will be persistent across kernel updates, as your configuration files should be in `etc` which isn't changed at boot