# xps15 touchpad pressure too sensitive. Settings have no effects

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, synaptics

I have a dell xps15 on which I installed kubuntu.

I managed to configure everything I want about the touchpad, except for the touch pressure sensitivity. Barely brushing on the touchpad will register as a click.

I tried to follow the various answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483707/14-04-touchpad-is-too-sensitive) but whatever the value I put for "Synaptics Finger", it has no effect.

Using synclient, every single settings works, except for FingerHigh and FingerLow (which is not suprising since those are the same as "Synaptics Finger".

The touchpad name in listed in xinput is DLL06E4:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad. Could it not support pressure detection?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same problem here on Dell Precision 5520.

Comment: Nothing. I tried every possible setting, but finally just had to get used to it. I think (even though that seems strange) that those settings are just not editable with this model of touchpad (don't know about yours, but it could be similar)