# Unwanted right clicking with touchpad and mouse on Lenovo e470

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I've just bought the laptop, without OS. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 via a bootable USB.

When using the touchpad and navigating around the screen I find that it automatically right-clicks, or when the cursor is hovering over text or the mozilla bar the right-click menu pops up.

I tried something from [14.04 Touchpad is too sensitive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483707/14-04-touchpad-is-too-sensitive), but if I do this the touchpad doesn't work (the cursor doesn't move), BUT the right-click menus still keep appearing). Original settings were 20 30 0.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a defective touchpad.

The simple way to fix this is to completely disable the touchpad in BIOS settings and use an external mouse.

If that fails, it might be worth contacting the seller to see what they'll offer for a defective touchpad.  Most likely what's happening is the touchpad giving spurious multi-touches -- depending on the laptop, a double or triple touch might be sent to the OS as a right click, resulting in your menu openings and other issues.  Disabling the touchpad will stop this completely, but if you need to use  the computer in situations where it isn't practical to use an external mouse (airline seats, for instance, or college lecture desks) it's something that will need to be fixed -- and might well be the reason your computer was for sale.

Comment: It was sealed, with papers and guarantee.

Comment: Then the seller should be able to examine and repair/replace the machine under warranty.  What you have is pretty clearly a hardware defect in the touchpad.  Be certain you back up (or even wipe) the machine before sending it for service, if you wind up doing that -- there's no guarantee you'll even get the same (serial number) hardware back.

Comment: Also i saw that when i connected a wireless mouse the right click doesn't work. I was having trouble to even write this message. the right click window continuously appeared...

Comment: Yep.  Warranty repair/replacement is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Few years later, the issue has sort of disappeared.
I've changed the keyboard and also uninstalled Skype. Because, in the last 6 months, if i was in a call and tried to write, everything was going crazy. In any case, i think this was a software problem, combined with some issues regarding the old keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

One of the OS settings is single tap to click, as in.. a light tap, not a full click. I always turn this off and rely on the actual button above the touchpad, or a hard click pres