# kubuntu 18.04: My touchpad sensitivity is way to high, configuring the touchpad in system settings doesn't affect anything

Tags: mouse

I am running kubuntu 18.04

Configuring the touchpad settings in system settings doesn't change anything for me.

I have tried changing the settings in the konsole using this post as a guide: [14.04 Touchpad is too sensitive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483707/14-04-touchpad-is-too-sensitive)

But I still cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Mouse & Touchpad.
2. Click on Mouse & Touchpad to open the panel.
3. Adjust the Pointer Speed slider until the pointer motion is comfortable for you. You will see one slider per each pointing device, such as mouse or touchpad.

There is an option for Touchpad sensitivity.

This is from the Help pages from Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-sensitivity.html.

Comment: OP asked to change sensitivity, not speed. There is NO option for Touchpad sensitivity in the control panel.