# Reduce SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad sensitivity on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics, hp-touchpad

- ProBook 4530s
- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Gnome fresh install

xinput list output

```
~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam [Fixed]: HP HD Web           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]

~$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (173):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (175): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (310): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (311): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (312):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (313):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (314):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (315):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (316):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (317):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (318):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (319):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (320):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (321):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (322):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (323):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (324):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (325): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (326): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (327): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (328): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (295): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (296):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (297):    0, 0
    Device Node (298):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (299):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (329):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (330):   1
```

I don't see the "Synaptics Finger" or similar properties. Any ideas on how to reduce the touchpad sensitivity on pressure? Which property may be the equivalent of "Synaptic Finger" in my case? I have already checked related posts but they all mention the "Synaptic Finger" prop.
My Mouse & Touchpad settings screen looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you configured touchpad sensitivity in your settings?

Comment: No, from the settings the only configurable property seems to be the "Touchpad Speed". I also installed Gnome Tweaks but didn't find any options for the pressure sensitivity. My problem is the touchpad is too sensitive on pressure.

Comment: That is a bit odd. I will do some research, and I will probably get back to you soon.

Comment: Here is a similar question. I don't know if it will help, as it is for KUbuntu, but it is essentially the same. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029999/kubuntu-18-04-my-touchpad-sensitivity-is-way-to-high-configuring-the-touchpad. It is also in the settings, and that does not seem to work right now. I will post these as an answer.

Comment: Here is another possibility: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad. I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried `xinput --set-prop 12 "Synaptics Finger" 50 80 257` even if the prop isn't shown in in list output but as expected didn't work. Got error `property 'Synaptics Finger' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`

Comment: Are you sure you installed the touchpad drivers for your  touchpad? Sometimes, the Ubuntu drivers are not ideal...

Comment: @NegoescutzStefilutz after the installation the touchpad was working so I chose not to install third party drivers. During the installation process I had an internet connection and I chose "Automatically download third-party drivers".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question. I don't know if it will help, as it is for KUbuntu, but it is essentially the same. [kubuntu 18.04: My touchpad sensitivity is way to high, configuring the touchpad in system settings doesn't affect anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029999/kubuntu-18-04-my-touchpad-sensitivity-is-way-to-high-configuring-the-touchpad). It is also in the settings, and that does not seem to work right now. Here is another possibility: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad. I hope it helps.

Comment: Tell me if this worked, if you please.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: I can't do much, then. I am sorry about that.