# Cannot change touchpad sensitivity - "property 'Synaptics Finger' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format"

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483707/14-04-touchpad-is-too-sensitive?noredirect=1&lq=1) in my Ubuntu 18.04 (HP laptop) but the terminal says:

`property 'Synaptics Finger' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`

I cannot find relevant option in `xinput --watch-props`. Here is the outcome:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (141):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (294): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (295): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (296):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (297):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (298):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (299):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (300):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (301):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (276):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (277):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (302):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (303):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (278):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (279):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (280):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (285): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (286): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (290): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (291): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (261): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (262):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (263):    0, 0
    Device Node (264):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (265):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (292):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (293):   1
```

I also have tried to set tapping to 0.5 `xinput --set-prop 11 294 0.5`  but it has turned off tapping completely.

Is there any possibility to reduce touchpad sensitivity?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` then restart